# CSS last child of a row

Tags: html, css, row, css-selectors

I am creating DIVs from a MySQL Query with a CSS `float: left;` style

 
all of them have a width of 300px and the wrapping container is set to 900px.

So after every 3rd Box, there is a new line.

but there is also the possibility to set a `<div class="clear"></div>` after the first or second DIV

Is it possible to remove right boarder from the `last-child` of a row? 

or maybe after the clear-Div?

http://jsfiddle.net/uq9zaav3/2/ 
example with background color, but it should be no problem to make it with border ;)

Comment: What you are after can't be achieved with pure CSS. Is javascript an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could apply nth-child for your first solution

```
.testbox:nth-child(3n) {
    background: blue;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/uq9zaav3/3/

For the second solution you have to declare when and where you want to use a clear div so it could also be done with nth-child(..).

Comment: yep thats the solution i knew, but i hoped there was another :/
   -   is there no posibility to change color of a div if its followed by another div class or by a specific div class?

Comment: @xQp There's no backward selector in CSS, therefore the answer is No.

Comment: As @HashemQolami said you can't go backward you could only trigger the next element of a div with class `clear`. But you can always add a class which will remove the margin directly to the last element of it's row. Not an elegant solution although

Answer (score 0):

why not give a try for jQuery

JS code

```
$(".thumb:nth-of-type(3n)").css({'background-color': 'yellow', 'margin-right': '0px' });
```

use

```
$(".testbox:nth-of-type(3n)").css({'background-color': 'yellow', 'border-right': '0px' });
```

Which selects every third child in the div

[**Full Screen**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/Lp9kngp0/show/)

[**JS**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/Lp9kngp0/)

Comment: that makes no sense doing it with jquery, ill get every 3rd yellow with that code without java/jquery by just using CSS3 and as i said my problem is that i need a rule for 'last child of a row' which is not working so i need to find another soluten but thx ;)